# Clarifai - Face Detect - Method Not Allowed

Tags: javascript, api, face-detection, clarifai

I'd be really greatful if someone could assist me in this error while using Clarifai Face Detection API

This is the code for the model that I used :

```
app.models.predict( {
      id: "a403429f2ddf4b49b307e318f00e528b",
      version: "34ce21a40cc24b6b96ffee54aabff139",
      }, this.state.input  )
      .then(
      function(response) {
        
        console.log(response.outputs[0].data.regions[0].region_info.bounding_box);
      },
      function(err) {
        
      }
    );
  }
```

This is the error that i got from dev tool

https://api.clarifai.com/v2/models/a403429f2ddf4b49b307e318f00e528b/versions/34ce21a40cc24b6b96ffee54aabff139/outputs

Which says : {"status":{"code":11103,"description":"Method not allowed","details":"Method Not Allowed"}}

I am not sure how to debug this, any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the Clarifai Models can be down or not working as they are constantly getting updated. A good way to check if the model you are using is up, is to check them on the clarifai website.
If that isn't working, then that means you will have to wait until their servers are back up. Another solution is to use a different version of their model that works like this one: `c0c0ac362b03416da06ab3fa36fb58e3`.

like:

```
app.models.predict( {
  id: "a403429f2ddf4b49b307e318f00e528b",
  version: "c0c0ac362b03416da06ab3fa36fb58e3",
  }, this.state.input  )
```

hope it will work. good luck! :)